# Connect to davs with emacs

Tags: emacs, webdav, tramp

I'm trying to access a remote davs server with emacs through tramp. I use the syntax

```
/davs:username@servername.fr: TAB
```

With ftp, this would ask for a password, connect to the server and open a completion list. But with davs Emacs gives the error `Package` tramp-gvfs' not supported`. Checking the messages buffer the error is linked to  "completion--some" so I'm not sure it has to do with tramp itself. In the messages buffer I also see

```
Opening connection for davs using scpc... \
Tramp: Opening connection for davs using scpc...done
byte-code: Process died
```

I tried to specify the port number by adding #2078 after servername.fr but it didn't make any difference.

The connection works fine with my file managers (Nautilus and Thunar) so I suppose gvfs is set up properly on my system. Where else should I look?

Answer (score 1):

You get this error message if Emacs is not compiled with DBus support, if it cannot connect to the session bus, or if neither `gvfs-fuse-daemon` nor `gvfsd-fuse` is running.  (See the definition of `tramp-gvfs-enabled`.)

I seem to remember that I had to start `gvfs-fuse-daemon` manually, but I'm not sure exactly what I did to get it work; this was a long time ago on a different computer...  Hopefully someone else can come up with a more complete answer.

Comment: Thanks for the hints! I use the Ubuntu emacs24 package. I suppose the maintainers should have activated dbus support but I'm not sure how to check. I have gvfsd-fuse running on my system. In emacs describe-variable doesn't find any `tramp-gvfs-enabled` though. Does it mean it's disabled?

Comment: Not necessarily. Try `M-x load-library RET tramp-gvfs` first and see if it's there after that.

Comment: Doing `load-library` I get the same error: `Package `tramp-gvfs' not supported`.

Comment: @Victor Me neither. `load-library` doesn't work for me. I guess it shows up the message because I'm trying to access a remote server in WSL, in my knowledge, WSL doesn't support fuse.